# Get Filename (label) from directory path in google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am working on a classification task on Google colab. The dataset I'm using for the task is on google drive and has the folder name as the label. e.g train/cat/img1.jpg, train/dog/img03.jpg

How can I extract the label from the folder name. I have tried using the code below but it is not extracting the folder name.

```
train_images = []
train_labels = []
for directory_path in glob.glob("/content/drive/My Drive/images/train/*"):
    label = directory_path.split("\\")[-1]
    print(label)
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.*")):
        print(img_path)
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (SIZE,SIZE))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        train_images.append(img)
        train_labels.append(label)

train_images = np.array(train_images)
train_labels = np.array(train_labels)
```

Comment: so you are trying to get the "cat" or "dog" part from the dir name? For example: given " train/cat/img1.jpg" you want to return cat?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the "cat" or "dog"

Comment: So you want to list the names of all folders in `train`? Are you open to using [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api) for this? Also, do you know the `train` folder id? ([here's](https://ploi.io/documentation/database/where-do-i-get-google-drive-folder-id) how to get it)

Comment: @lamblichus I have been able to connect to google drive by mounting and allowing access to the drive. But the problem lies in getting the folder names.

Comment: Hi, would you consider answering the questions I made? I think these are relevant and could be useful in finding a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hello @lamblichus, I want to list the names of all folders in train, I am open to using DriveAPI and I know the folder ID. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the parent folder id, you can use [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to get the list of files which have `train` as their parent folder, using `q` parameter:

```
'q': "'{TRAIN_FOLDER_ID}' in parents"
```

You'd just have to modify the example [Listing files in Google Drive](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/drive.ipynb#scrollTo=hqJvrn8xsgd0) with a modified request:

```
filenames = drive.ListFile({
  'q': "'{TRAIN_FOLDER_ID}' in parents", 
  'fields': "files(name)"
}).GetList()
```

#### Reference:

- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files)

Comment: Yes, I have gotten it. Thanks

Comment: @OladosuOladimeji For documentation purposes, please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking the "checkmark" icon underneath the vote buttons.